# Does a maximal subgroup have to contain the center?

Tags: group-theory, maximal-subgroup

Let $G$ be a non-abelian group with center $Z(G)$, and let $H$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$ which is non-abelian. Is it true that $Z(G)\leq H$?

I am trying to prove that it is true by arguing that if not, then the group $J:=\langle H,Z(G)\rangle$ is going to be a proper subgroup of $G$ containing $H$, which would contradict the maximality of $H$. It is clear that $H$ is a proper subgroup of $J$, but I am not sure how to show that $J$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, i.e that $J\neq G$.

It may be that the statement is not true in general, but in particular I want to prove it when $G=SL(2,q)$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

A fairly straightforward example is $H\times C_p$ where $H$
is a non-Abelian simple group and $C_p$ is cyclic of prime order $p$.
The centre is $C_p$ and $H$ is maximal.

Comment: Thanks for the counter example. Are there any particular cases of $G$ for which the statement might hold, e.g. what if $G=SL_{2}(q)$? Then the center is $\{\pm I_{2}\}$, where $I_{2}$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your statement is true if $H$ is assumed to be *abelian*: if $G$ is a non-abelian group, $H$ a abelian maximal subgroup, then $Z(G) \subseteq H$. Proof: if $G=HZ(G)$ then clearly $G$ would be abelian, hence you must have $H=HZ(G)$. 
Although you cannot always interchange *maximal* and *abelian* (a maximal abelian subgroup can be something different than an abelian maximal subgroup), the statement remains true if you do that in this case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I should have put that $H$ is non-abelian in the statement. I'll edit it.